# focus() not really working in a React codesandbox on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, codesandbox

I have a totally simple React sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-glitter-wgj13s?file=/src/App.js:335-349
It's supposed for the button First to focus after clicking the Second one and vice versa.
Unfortunately the blue border is not showing around the focused button. Is anybody able to explain why?

Edit: It seems to be the case just on Chrome (105.0.5195.125) and Firefox(104.0.2 (64-bit)).
Works well on Safari(15.6.1 (17613.3.9.1.16)). I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: it is working. how did you decide it was not working?

Comment: @nullptr I don't see a blue line around, tried on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: looks like it works in Safari, but after few clicks it stops focusing again

Comment: it's working for me on chrome. try adding a `button:focus{border:5px solid red}` in your css

Comment: @nullptr thanks, I tested that onClick with console.log so I saw it indeed logged to console, so was actually curious what's the difference in how Chrome and Safari handles it that I need to touch CSS in order to get it in Chrome or FF

Comment: i think at least chrome only adds the outline when you are navigating with the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is not working?

You have not added any onFocus properties on the second button to check if it is getting the focus or not. Try the below code and click on the first button. The console will have a log ("Second button is on focus!")

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.firstRef = React.createRef();
    this.secondRef = React.createRef();
  }
  handleFocus() {
    console.log("Second button is on focus!"); // <-- This will be executed on 1st button click
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.secondRef.current.focus();
          }}
          ref={this.firstRef}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "lime" }}
        >
          <h1>First</h1>
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.firstRef.current.focus();
          }}
          ref={this.secondRef}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus} // <-- Added on-focus property to 2nd button
        >
          <h1>Second</h1>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Hemant! 
I don't see a blue line around, that's how I know.
It looks like issue is specific to Chrome and Firefox for me. I see it's working on Safari.